# How to generate output in different tabs for simultaneously executing queries in Oracle SQL Developers?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-testing

We are testing a table. There are 20 different tests to be done in the given table. So there are 20 different queries we execute. Is there a way that I run 20 different queries on the same table and get 20 different outputs generated for the same table? We are using Oracle SQL Developer and Standard Edition 2.

Please let me know if it is possible as it will save a lot of time. If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/06/running-multiple-queries-in-oracle-sql-developer/ check this link

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you just need to check the "Show query results in new tabs" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: This is good. Thanks.